# Call another function inside a module: The containing arrow function captures the global value of 'this'

Tags: typescript

How Can I call `test()` from `customFunction()`?

```
export default {
  test: () => {
    console.log('test called')
  },
  customFunction: (parent: any, args: any, ctx: any, info: any) => {
    this.test()
  }
}
```

I am having the error: `The containing arrow function captures the global value of 'this'.` on `this`:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just don't use an arrow function but a function expression instead?

Comment: When I do functions instead of arrows, this is undefined.. See here: https://snipboard.io/4L6qv2.jpg

Comment: How exactly do you call those?

Comment: simple import:  `import customFunctionMutation from './customFunctionMutation'`

Comment: There is no `customFunctionMutation` in your code and you don't invoke it in your example.

Answer (score 1):

Make an object and reference it inside the method.

```ts
const obj = {
  test() {
    console.log('test called')
  },
  customFunction(parent: any, args: any, ctx: any, info: any) {
    obj.test()
  }
}

export default obj
```